# How can i make my URL seo friendly by removing %?

Tags: express, ejs

I am using ejs, expressjs, mongoose and I am rendering templates based on ejs.

One of my landing page has it tile in url. Title is input from user, he may enter with spaces or without spaces. If he entered it with spaces I'm getting an URL like below.

The below URL is complete non SEO friendly so I want to make it plain text with hyphens

```
http://localhost:8080/photoapp/awesome%20baby%20srija
```

I want to remove % and replace with - in my URL to make it SEO friendly. how can I do that?

My ejs template:

```
<td><a href="photoapp/<%=camp.Title%>"> Campaign Link</a>    </td>
```

My route: This is my post route which is rendering particular page code. How can i achieve this with javascript tags or ejs tricks.

```
 exports.getCampList = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    Campaign.find({userId:req.user._id}, (err, campaign) => {
      if(req.user){
        res.render('admin/campaign-list', {
          title: 'Campaigns',
          camplist : campaign

        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I want remove all unnecessary code and make it url friendly website

Comment: You've to add a 'slug' column to your db table and slugify the title...

Answer (score 0):

You can use slugify or use regex to replace characters and spaces with a hyphen.

```
function slugify_text(Text){
return Text
    
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "-")
    .replace(/(^\s*-)|(-\s*$)/g, '');}
```

You can use this to slugify the page name to an SEO friendly URL.